# Tag wikis with pending edits make it look like I am the one who proposed the edit

Tags: bug, status-completed, suggested-edits, tag-wiki

I took a look at the recently-created tags in the Moderator Tools (on SO) and clicked on one of them.  When I then clicked `learn more...` to see the tag wiki, it said:

> **Thanks for your edit!**
>   This edit will be visible only to you until it is [peer reviewed](https://stackoverflow.com/suggested-edits/2573189).

The strange thing is, I wasn't the one who proposed the edit, and the edit was not visible to me.  I checked a couple other tags with pending edits, and it seems they all have the same strange behavior.

Comment: On the one hand, I'm happy to see that they're [finally linkifying these](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/255841/there-should-be-a-link-to-the-review-entry-in-the-header-after-suggesting-a-tag). On the other... the bugginess! It burns us!

Comment: Derp. I bet that's my fault - made a change recently to show a message with a link to the suggested edit instead of a link-less message. I'll take a look tomorrow and fix it up.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yeah, that was my bad. Fix coming in the next build (`rev 2016.6.23.4677` on MSE/MSO, `rev 2016.6.23.3705` elsewhere).

Thanks for the report!